# Error while converting List of objects to Datatable

Tags: c#, list, class, object, datatable

Hello I have the following method.

```
public static DataTable ConvertToDataTable<T>(List<T> lstData)
{
    PropertyDescriptorCollection objPropertiesCollection = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
    DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();

    foreach (PropertyDescriptor objProperty in objPropertiesCollection)
    {
        dtResult.Columns.Add(objProperty.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objProperty.PropertyType) ?? objProperty.PropertyType);
    }

    foreach (T item in lstData)
    {
        DataRow dr = dtResult.NewRow();

        foreach (PropertyDescriptor objProperty in objPropertiesCollection)
        {
            dr[objProperty.Name] = objProperty.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
        }

        dtResult.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    return dtResult;
}
```

and I have the following Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ClientesPagos.Clases
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Servicio
    {
        public int IdServicio;
        public string Nombre;
        public string Descripcion;
        public string Imagen;
        public decimal Precio;
        public int Cantidad;
        public decimal Total;

        public Servicio()
        {

        }

        public Servicio(int id, string nombre, string descripcion, string img, decimal precio, int cantidad)
        {
            IdServicio = id;
            Nombre = nombre;
            Descripcion = descripcion;
            Imagen = img;
            Precio = precio;
            Cantidad = cantidad;
            Total = cantidad * precio;
        }
    }
}
```

now the problem is on the first line of the method

```
PropertyDescriptorCollection objPropertiesCollection =   
    TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
```

It does not fill objPropertiesCollection and therefore the following instructions don't work.

Is there something wrong on the class, that it may not be working on the first Method?

Comment: Properties != Fields.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for not to use CopyToDataTable();. I think it will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get properties an you should change your fields to properties.
Those are properties:

```
public int IdServicio {get; set;}
public string Nombre { get; set; }
public string Descripcion { get; set; }
public string Imagen { get; set; }
public decimal Precio { get; set; }
public int Cantidad { get; set; }
public decimal Total { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to convert "everything" to a `DataTable`? Then i would use the `CopyToDataTable` approach on MSDN with it's `ObjectShredder` class.

[How to: Implement CopyToDataTable Where the Generic Type T Is Not a DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx)

```
public class ObjectShredder<T> {
    private System.Reflection.FieldInfo[] _fi;
    private System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] _pi;
    private System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, int> _ordinalMap;
    private System.Type _type;

    // ObjectShredder constructor.
    public ObjectShredder() {
        _type = typeof(T);
        _fi = _type.GetFields();
        _pi = _type.GetProperties();
        _ordinalMap = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Loads a DataTable from a sequence of objects.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">The sequence of objects to load into the DataTable.</param>
    /// <param name="table">The input table. The schema of the table must match that 
    /// the type T.  If the table is null, a new table is created with a schema 
    /// created from the public properties and fields of the type T.</param>
    /// <param name="options">Specifies how values from the source sequence will be applied to 
    /// existing rows in the table.</param>
    /// <returns>A DataTable created from the source sequence.</returns>
    public DataTable Shred(IEnumerable<T> source, DataTable table, LoadOption? options) {
        // Load the table from the scalar sequence if T is a primitive type.
        if (typeof(T).IsPrimitive) {
            return ShredPrimitive(source, table, options);
        }

        // Create a new table if the input table is null.
        if (table == null) {
            table = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);
        }

        // Initialize the ordinal map and extend the table schema based on type T.
        table = ExtendTable(table, typeof(T));

        // Enumerate the source sequence and load the object values into rows.
        table.BeginLoadData();
        using (IEnumerator<T> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
            while (e.MoveNext()) {
                if (options != null) {
                    table.LoadDataRow(ShredObject(table, e.Current), (LoadOption)options);
                } else {
                    table.LoadDataRow(ShredObject(table, e.Current), true);
                }
            }
        }
        table.EndLoadData();

        // Return the table.
        return table;
    }

    public DataTable ShredPrimitive(IEnumerable<T> source, DataTable table, LoadOption? options) {
        // Create a new table if the input table is null.
        if (table == null) {
            table = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);
        }

        if (!table.Columns.Contains("Value")) {
            table.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(T));
        }

        // Enumerate the source sequence and load the scalar values into rows.
        table.BeginLoadData();
        using (IEnumerator<T> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
            Object[] values = new object[table.Columns.Count];
            while (e.MoveNext()) {
                values[table.Columns["Value"].Ordinal] = e.Current;

                if (options != null) {
                    table.LoadDataRow(values, (LoadOption)options);
                } else {
                    table.LoadDataRow(values, true);
                }
            }
        }
        table.EndLoadData();

        // Return the table.
        return table;
    }

    public object[] ShredObject(DataTable table, T instance) {

        FieldInfo[] fi = _fi;
        PropertyInfo[] pi = _pi;

        if (instance.GetType() != typeof(T)) {
            // If the instance is derived from T, extend the table schema
            // and get the properties and fields.
            ExtendTable(table, instance.GetType());
            fi = instance.GetType().GetFields();
            pi = instance.GetType().GetProperties();
        }

        // Add the property and field values of the instance to an array.
        Object[] values = new object[table.Columns.Count];
        foreach (FieldInfo f in fi) {
            values[_ordinalMap[f.Name]] = f.GetValue(instance);
        }

        foreach (PropertyInfo p in pi) {
            values[_ordinalMap[p.Name]] = p.GetValue(instance, null);
        }

        // Return the property and field values of the instance.
        return values;
    }

    public DataTable ExtendTable(DataTable table, Type type) {
        // Extend the table schema if the input table was null or if the value 
        // in the sequence is derived from type T.            
        foreach (FieldInfo f in type.GetFields()) {
            if (!_ordinalMap.ContainsKey(f.Name)) {
                // Add the field as a column in the table if it doesn't exist
                // already.
                DataColumn dc = table.Columns.Contains(f.Name) ? table.Columns[f.Name]
                    : table.Columns.Add(f.Name, f.FieldType);

                // Add the field to the ordinal map.
                _ordinalMap.Add(f.Name, dc.Ordinal);
            }
        }
        foreach (PropertyInfo p in type.GetProperties()) {
            if (!_ordinalMap.ContainsKey(p.Name)) {
                // Add the property as a column in the table if it doesn't exist
                // already.
                DataColumn dc = table.Columns.Contains(p.Name) ? table.Columns[p.Name]
                    : table.Columns.Add(p.Name, p.PropertyType);

                // Add the property to the ordinal map.
                _ordinalMap.Add(p.Name, dc.Ordinal);
            }
        }

        // Return the table.
        return table;
    }
}
```

Now you can add these extensions:

```
public static class CustomLINQtoDataSetMethods {
    public static DataTable CopyToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) {
        return new ObjectShredder<T>().Shred(source, null, null);
    }

    public static DataTable CopyToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
                                                DataTable table, LoadOption? options) {
        return new ObjectShredder<T>().Shred(source, table, options);
    }  
}
```

Now `CopyToDataTable` works with any kind of `IEnumerable<T>`(even anonymous types) not only with `DataRows`.